# Array string format to real array

Tags: python, arrays, string

I have this string

```
'[334.0, 223.0, 41.0, 819.0]'
```

And I need to transform this in this array:

```
[334.0, 223.0, 41.0, 819.0]
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the **ast** module.

**Ex:**

```
import ast
print(ast.literal_eval('[334.0, 223.0, 41.0, 819.0]'))
```

**output:**

```
[334.0, 223.0, 41.0, 819.0]
```

Comment: Really nice dude, can you explain to me how it works?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval

Comment: much love to you man

Comment: You are welcome :)

Comment: I cant, I have to wait 15mins (1 left) but I will

Answer (score 1):

Simple one-liner with no extra imports:

```
a = '[334.0, 223.0, 41.0, 819.0]'

b = [ float(i) for i in a[1:-1].split(',') ]

print b
```

Output:

```
[334.0, 223.0, 41.0, 819.0]
```

Comment: `float(223)` will produce the output `223.0`. (It seems that the commenter deleted the comment. This was in response to: What if we have an integer value in `a`).

Answer (score -1):

What about `eval`?

That would evaluate a string as if it is a python code.

For example:

```
string='[334.0, 223.0, 41.0, 819.0]'
a = eval(string)
print(a[0])
```

output:

```
334.0
```

Comment: [Eval is evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: @soon Only if you do not know what you are doing. ;)

Comment: Let's be honest - most of developers do not know what are they doing. `ast.literal_eval` behaves like `eval` for objects and it is safe